Revision without reviewer comments
Last year october, i have submitted one of my review paper to a reputed journal in springer.On march i received a mail saying that a minor revision is required along with reviewers comments.I have done all the corrections and have submitted back to the journal with all those needed documents.On the same day of submission, i have received an another mail saying that reviewers have suggested a minor revision but under the heading comments for the author, it was blank.
I have sent mail to the editor, and others,but did not get any reply.After waiting 3 days, i have submitted the revision saying that i did not receive any comments,so i am sending back my first revision details.
But the same thing happened again, i have recieved a mail for next minor revision without any reviewer comments.
What should i do.I am confused

It looks like you've asked this question before; you received a lot of helpful comments there. Better to edit that version of the question rather than continue reposting new versions.
